# Submit form through javascript without refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently submitting a form in javascript, and I've enabled AJAX for the form and the AJAX works perfectly when you submit the form manually, however not when javascript does it and it causes a refresh.

My current code is:

```
:javascript
  wistiaEmbed = Wistia.embed("#{@chapter.video_id}", {
    autoPlay: true,
    videoFoam: true,
    playerColor: 'E68482'
  });
  wistiaEmbed.bind("end", function () {
    document.getElementById('target').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('finished').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('new_chapter_completion').submit();
  });
```

and my form looks like this:

```
= form_for current_user.chapter_completions.build, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f|
 = hidden_field_tag :chapter_id, @chapter.id
 = f.submit
```

now I realize the problem here comes from the .submit(); I want to know what to use instead of the .submit();.

Furthermore I'd like for the form to not really be visible, but instead that javascript just submits this data, is it possible? Now I need to have the form on the site, because it has the #id.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> works perfectly when you submit the form manually

I suppose, manually - is submitting via clicking on the submit button, right?

If so, why not try this workaround?

In HTML:

```
<form id="new_chapter_completion">
<!-- your input fields here -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-btn">
</form>
```

In JS (using JQuery, but it is possible to do this without it):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code goes here, but insted of
    // document.getElementById('new_chapter_completion').submit();
    // you are doing this:
    $('#submit-btn').trigger('click'); // immitation of real click
});
```

> Furthermore I'd like for the form to not really be visible

Hiding elements is rather about using CSS, I think. There are different tricks. For example, make the main wrapper DIV of you page (CSS):

```
position:relative;
z-index:10;
```

and your form inside this wrapper (#new_chapter_completion):

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:1;
```

Comment: this seems incredibly dirty.

Comment: Well, if you are talking about CSS - maybe. You can dynamically create a form with specific id using JS (without HTML and CSS at all), however, in this case, you will only have to use the submit() method, no click on real button. What about JS, submit() - is the only method for form submitting, as you know. If there would be no other solutions suggested in this topic, at the worst, my workaround should work.